# Windows 10 Rtree installation successful from .whl file, but error when running code

Tags: ctypes, geopandas, r-tree, libspatialindex

I am running Python 3.7, 64bit on Windows 10 and trying desperately to get Rtree running. I use the package Rtree-0.9.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl from Christoph Gohlke (https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

I have tried for very long to get it to work, but keep on getting the following error message when running a script that uses geopandas.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\rtree\core.py", line 90, in <module>
    rt = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(here, 'spatialindex_c.dll'))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

The installation of the whl-package should include the libspatialindex files, but they are not found when running the code. I tried to use Python 2.7 first to run it, then installed Python 3.7. I've checked all the dependencies and checked whether the "spatialindex_c.dll" files are at the right place, but nothing helps. Would be great to get an answer on that.

Comment: Try Rtree-0.9.3

Comment: Thanks, that version worked!